# How to change the BTRFS device ID and does it determine the I/O priority?

Tags: btrfs

Here's my simple setup:

```
~$ sudo btrfs device usage /
/dev/sda3, ID: 4
   Device size:           100.00GiB
   Device slack:          103.01MiB
   Data,RAID1:             73.00GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          2.00GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:            24.87GiB

/dev/sdb3, ID: 5
   Device size:           100.00GiB
   Device slack:              0.00B
   Data,RAID1:             73.00GiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          2.00GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:            24.97GiB
```

```
# /etc/fstab
UUID=.....  /  auto  compress=zlib,autodefrag,noatime  0  1
```

```
~$ mount | grep btrfs
/dev/sda3 on / type btrfs (rw,noatime,compress=zlib:3,space_cache,autodefrag,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

Is it possible to interchange the devices so that `sdb3` gets the lower ID (possibly reset to `1`) and hence appears in `mount` results?

Does the device order affect which device will be given priority for I/O operations?

Comment: guess just switch cables physical is no option?

Comment: @alecxs unfortunately no.

Comment: Rather than `mount | grep btrfs`, would `mount -t btrfs` work for you?  Just curious ... What is the importance of the btrfs devices/partitions in the output of `mount`?

Comment: @alecxs thanks but that's above my range :)